# Merging two child tables from two different databases

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL SERVER 2012 MERGE statement. I need to merge two child tables from different databases into one table.

DatabaseA:

1. Parent  Invoice Table
   -InvNo int
   -InvDate Datetime
   -CustomerName varchar(50)
   -InvVal double
2. Child  InvoiceDet table
   -InvNo int
   -InvDate DateTime
   -ItemName varchar(50)
   -Qty int
   -Rate double

DataBaseB: contains the same above structure.

1. Now I want to merge the two child tables into a single child table without loss of data. A single invoice may contain same items with different / equal quantity. How do I merge these child tables.

Thanks in advance,
Senthil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to be able to query both tables at the same time. You may need linked server or openrowset (or friends).

Seeing as how you just want to merge child tables, the parent table is irrelevant.

Then you need to figure out the logic of the merge. Let's say you want merge A into B. There are three types of situations:

- MATCHED
- NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]
- NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE

What do you want to do in each situation?

After you have the design, the docs (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) has very good examples.

Basically you want:

```
MERGE child as target
USING (select ... from databaseA.dbo.child) as source (...)
ON (conditions)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET target.v = source.v
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (v) VALUES (source.v)
-- WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  -- Don't delete anything
;
```